# How can I get the result from docker about executing some script ?

Tags: docker, bamboo

I have a bamboo server, that build some .bin file. After creating .bin file I want to check if my program can install successfully. I installed on my build server docker and wrote the next script:

```
docker create -i -t --name my_container my_image #create container with Ubuntu 14.04
docker cp my_install.bin my_container:/install.bin #copy my .bin file to container
docker start my_container #launch container
docker exec -i my_container /install.bin #launch this script
```

After installation the program return 0 - if program has been installed succesfully and 1 otherwise. How can I retrieve this result on bamboo server, which launch this docker and this script.
The main idea is to implement, that Atlassion bamboo showed green if program has been installed correctly and red - otherwise. 
[Atlassian bamboo - expected result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TEiXV.png)

Answer (score 0):

After the script finishes running you could run

```
echo $?
```

and this will display either 0 if was successful or 1 if was unsuccessful or any other error code that might have been set